# Is main() function better on top of all other functions?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

My college professor told me that main functions should be defined on top of other function definitions. We should use a forward declaration in order to accomplish this (we use C at that time). So yes, my question is why should `main()` be on top of other function definitions? Does this apply to all programming languages that uses `main()` as the entry point of the program?

Comment: Other functions should be in completely different files.

Comment: Okay but for example it's just a very little program and I really want to save space from creating another file. Which would be the best location for `main()`? Why?

Comment: @BryanJames: If your code is so small that it reasonably fits into one file... who cares what comes first? It won't mean anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's largely a matter of personal preference, although some places may make it a formal coding standard.  C itself doesn't care.

For my part, if I'm defining multiple functions in a single source file, I will define the called functions before the caller:

```
void foo( void )
{
  ...
}

void bar( void )
{
  ...
  foo();
  ...
}

int main( void )
{
  ...
  bar();
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
int main( void )
{
   void bar( void );
   ...  
   bar();
   ...
}

void bar( void )
{
  void foo( void );
  ...
  foo();
}

void foo( void )
{
  ...
}
```

The problem with using forward declarations is you increase your maintenance burden; if you change the function prototype (return type, number and/or types of parameters), you now have to make those changes in *two* places instead of one.

Of course, if you're calling functions defined in a different source file, you need separate declarations (preferably grouped into their own header file):

```
/**
 * functions.c
 */
#include "functions.h"

void foo( void )     // Note that I'm still defining called functions
{                    // before their callers, even though in this case
  ...                // it's not necessary, since "functions.h" contains
}                    // the declaration for foo().

void bar( void )
{
  ...
  foo();
  ...
}

/**
 * functions.h
 */
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

void foo( void );
void bar( void );

#endif

/**
 * main.c
 */
#include "functions.h"

int main( void )
{
  ...
  bar();
  ...
}
```

> Does this apply to all programming languages that uses main() as the entry point of the program?

Again, for most of those languages, it's strictly a matter of style and personal preference.  The language definition itself doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

The best place is somewhere that people can find it.

In the middle of a very large file is bad.  At the top is good, but others might prefer right at the bottom.

Forward declaring main() doesn't help, and is often pointless anyway - because it's very unusual to explicitly call main() from within your code.